# Magento1 : Display custom variable from admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, php

I want to display Magento custom variable from the Admin configurations, so when I add the calling inside my custom configurations it didn't get the value of it, you can see the below example:

```
        <bank_sms translate="label">
            <label>Bank Orders Ensure Message</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <fields>
                <active_banksms translate="label">
                    <label>Enable Bank Orders SMS</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                </active_banksms>
                <message_bank>
                    <label>Bank Orders SMS</label>
                    <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <depends>
                        <active_banksms>1</active_banksms>
                    </depends>
                </message_bank>
            </fields>
        </bank_sms>
```

[image]

After I echo the configurations, it give me the same content in it (`Your order  {{customVar code=verifyOrder}}`). So is there a way to print the value of the customVar tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for custom variable `customvarDirective` is used.

Try below code

```
$helper = Mage::helper('cms');
$processor = $helper->getPageTemplateProcessor();
$html = $processor->filter(<Pass Your Config message_bank>);
```